# Set translation to another language into youtube subtitle by using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I've a simple chrome extension, i want to change subtitle/caption language to another language on window.load or any method:

```
window.onload = function () {
    change_subtitle_to("ar");
}
function change_subtitle_to(str){
// ??!
}
```